# Source for 'EVERY living organism uses ATP as energy carrier', and can we make a synthetic one that doesn't?

Tags: cell-biology, mitochondria, synthetic-biology

I have read it repeatedly that 'all living organisms use ATP as an energy currency etc' and 'some use GTP in addition'. However I am yet to find a reliable resource, rather than just quora/reddit/researchgate posts, that states this.

Also, would it be possible to create a synthetic organism which does not use ATP? Or GTP? What might be the best energy currency to use then?

Answer (score 3):

Well your request for a *source* is rather like asking who first reported that 2+2=4. Not quite, but that should give the idea to someone who has not studied biochemistry. I doubt that you will find a source, but the following from [Jacques Monod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Monod) — the Nobel laureate — is worth quoting:

> “Anything found to be true of *E. coli* must also be true of elephants.”

In fact, this turns out **not** to be true for *anything*, but it is true of the role of ATP.

The better question, I think, is *not* what the **source** of such a quotation is, but what is the **evidence** for such an opinion. The evidence that has accumulated over the last 80 years or so is from examining the metabolic pathways present in different organisms, and, more recently, sequencing their genomes to identify the genes for various enzymes. What has been observed is a core of common pathways, involving a core mechanism of energy metabolism involving ATP. This is consistent with the idea that this arose early in evolution and was fixed in the last common ancestor of living things.

If you want a more recent source to the ideas above, I suggest another SE Biology question, [*Immortal genes common to all organisms*](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/69715/immortal-genes-common-to-all-organisms), may provide a starting point.